# Unable to import data from web in microsoft excel while creating a connection with website

Tags: excel, model, powerbi

I can import table from the website "https://etfdb.com/etfs/country/us/" on Power BI, but I am unable to import the table from the website on excel while creating a connection.

there are total of 60+ pages on the website and i need table for "ETF list" so i can retrieve all the pages on excel.

[image]

Please suggest retrieving all the table on excel.

I tried to edit the power query code with changing the page range from 1 to 69 but out of 69 times the data output in the excel is only of 1st page and all of the data retrieve is 69 times of each data on first page.

I was expecting the all pages data will be retrieved if power query code can be changed but nothing happend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you arrived to that but using Anonymous connection this is what I see:

[image]

If you take the very first table you have everything.

The use PowerQuery to use the first line as the column name and you are done